# Is "More than one teacher..." singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, singular-subject-and-verb

I encountered a problem:

> More than one teacher ***is/are*** going to bring the students to a trip.

Can you help me with this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are more than one teacher. There are more teachers than one. "More than one" is of course plural.

Comment: Also related: [Which is correct: “one or more is” or “one or more are”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13284)

Comment: @RamPillai Compare "more than **one child** ***is***" and "more than **two children** ***are***"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subject–verb agreement — two schools of thought?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69650/subject-verb-agreement-two-schools-of-thought) "Don't take any notice of teachers and text-books in such matters. Nor of logic. It is good to say 'More than one passenger was hurt,' although more than one equals at least two and therefore logically the verb ought to be plural _were_ not singular _was_!" (C.S. Lewis, letter to Joan, June 26, 1956).

Comment: @Ram Pillai CS Lewis has more authority, I believe.

Comment: "is" would be most idiomatic in the US.

Comment: A couple of centuries ago, [both versions were equally common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+is+more+than+one%2Cthere+are+more+than+one&year_start=1700&year_end=1840&corpus=29&smoothing=20) But it's usually singular *there **is** more than one* today, both sides of the pond.